# Open embedded Textfile using Notepad

Tags: c#

I have the following problem. I want to open an embedded textfile (agb.txt) using "notepad.exe". I've got the following code:

```
private void linkLabel4_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
   string editorPath = Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\notepad.exe";
   var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(editorPath)
   {
      //Start Maximized
      WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized,
      Arguments = "agb.txt"
   };
   //Start notepad.exe (agb.txt)
   Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

When I start the program and click the Linklabel, Notpad.exe open up but can't find the embedded file (obviously). So is there a kinda 'Workaround'?

Comment: What did you tried so far?
Did you think about extracting the embedded resource into a temp folder?

Comment: @AlexH, I don't want to extract anything. I just want to start it right from the embedded source. Maby there is another solution without notepad.exe?

Comment: @Shad0w because notepad.exe can only open files ( i think ) you have to extract it.
You can use the 'temp'-Folder and delete the file after closing notepad.

Comment: Surely you need to put the path of agb.txt. Notepad is going to default to the Windows system directory and it's pretty unlikely your file is located there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about saving the file to `%TEMP%` and then simply calling

`Process.Start(@"c:\temp\agb.txt");`

(this will actually open the file in whatever application is registered to load it)

Comment: The value of `%TEMP%` is very likely not going to be `C:\temp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can start Nodepad.exe and then "send" the text from the embedded file to it.
Instead of my hardcoded string, you would read the content of the file into a string and then call DoSendMessage(stringWithYourFileContent);

This question and answer is a good resource for reading the content of the embedded file: [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSendMessage("Sending a message, a message from me to you");
    }



    private static void DoSendMessage(string message)
    {
        Process notepad = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe"));
        notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

        if (notepad != null)
        {
            IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
            SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, message);
        }
    }
}
```

> The constant 0x000c of SendMessage  is documented here 
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx
>   . The constant says SETTEXT which really means that the text in
>   notepad will be replaced if you send more than one message using this
>   constant.